# Complex valued distributions in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to use [`TransformedDistribution`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/TransformedDistribution) to create a complex-valued Gaussian distribution from a given a 2D scale vector?  I'd rather have the distribution object automatically produce complex dtypes when sampled, for example.